# How to Kill Processes in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, kill

I used the following bash code:

```
for pid in `top -n 1 | awk '{if($8 == "R") print $1;}'`
do
  kill $pid
done
```

It says:

```
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29162: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29165: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29166: arguments must be process or job IDs
./kill.sh: line 3: kill: 29169: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

What causes this error and how do I kill processes in Bash?

Comment: `top` issues a header you need to skip over

Comment: What is `$8 == "R"` doing in awk command?

Comment: @anubhava, Checks if the 8th field is `R`

Comment: :) I think that much I also know but on my OSX 8th field is `MEM`. I think `top` command's output varies on every OS.

Comment: @anubhava, It's the process state on GNU/Linux. R means running or ready to run.

Comment: I think the title is misleading... you _are_ using BASH correct? Also, don't use backticks (`\`commands\``). Use `$(commands)`

Answer (score 2):

I usuallly use:

```
pkill <process name>
```

In your case:

```
pkill R
```

Note that this will kill all the running instances of `R`, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this `awk` command is not returning any reliable data, in any case theres a much easier way:

```
kill `pidof R`
```

Or:

```
killall R
```

Comment: will this kill all current running processes? including the shell itself?

Comment: It will kill all running processes of `R`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there may be a (possibly aliased) script `kill.sh` in your current directory which is acting as an intermediary and calling the `kill` builtin. However, the script is passing the wrong arguments to the builtin. (I can't give details without seeing the script.)

#### Solution.

Your command will work fine using the `kill` builtin. The simplest solution is to ensure you use the bash builtin `kill`. Execute:

```
chmod a-x kill.sh
unalias kill
unset -f kill
```

This will prevent the script from running and remove any alias or function that may interfere with your use of the `kill` builtin.

#### Note.

You can also simplify your command:

```
kill `top -n 1 | awk '{if($8 == "R") print $1;}'`
```

#### Alternatively...

You can also use `builtin` to bypass any functions and aliases:

```
builtin kill `top -n 1 | awk '{if($8 == "R") print $1;}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

`top` issues a header you need to suppress or skip over.

Or maybe you can use `ps` since its output is highly configurable.

Also note that `kill` accepts multiple PIDs, so there's no reason to employ a loop.

```
kill $( ps h -o pid,state | awk '$2 == "R" { print $1 }' )
```

Comment: Better written as `... awk '$2 == "R" { print $1 }' ...` ("better" since it's shorter, and slightly more efficient).

Comment: @lcd047, Thanks, don't know `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `awk`, `sed` can provide `pid` isolation in the list for `kill`:

```
kill $(ps h -o pid,state | grep R | sed -e 's/\s.*$//')
```

Basically, the opposite side of the same coin.

Comment: Because it was late and I wasn't thinking as clearly as you are `:p`. Thank you -- fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
top -n 1 | awk '{print "(" $1 ") - (" $8 ")";}'
```

to understand how $1 and $8 are evaluated

Please also post the content of ./kill.sh and explain the purpose of this script

Comment: Well, the `kill.sh` would be the debugging script for the bash builtin `kill`, normally located in `/usr/share/bashdb/command/kill.sh`. I'm not sure what's going on with this error, though. As for the `awk` command, clear that the OP know how `$1` and `$8` are evaluated. With the default columns, the command given will print the PIDs of processes with a process status of "Running". Also, the error gives the arguments that were passed to kill, and they appear to be PIDs.

Comment: Which distro? on mine, for example default columns are
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
And withouth the content of kill.sh no further analysis is possible

Comment: Alessandro: (1) That's the same as on my system (and the OP's). The "S" column is the status of the process ("R" stands for "Running", "S" for "Sleeping", etc). (2) I initially assumed the `kill.sh` was the system's, but I now think it must be the OP's. I suppose it must also be aliased to `kill`... The script is apparently passing the wrong arguments to the builtin (although they _look_ like valid PIDs, which is odd). The OP's command should work fine with the `kill` builtin.